# Phonegap Build 6.5, iOS... ajax calls not working

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, phonegap

Ok, so I have been tasked to update an old Phonegap/jQuery app. It is a couple of years out of date, but it has been in the store for a while and is working fine.

I need to add a couple of new features, but most of the code is untouched.

So my problem is, I cannot get my $.ajax calls on **iOS** to work for the life of me. I have been reading a billion posts and have done all of the following without luck:

**Access Origin**

```
<access origin='*' />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

**Platform stuff**

```
  <platform name="ios">
      <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
      <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
   </platform>
```

**Added this plugin**

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-transport-security" source="npm" spec="0.1.2" />
```

I have this plugin too, but from what I understand it is no longer needed for iOS

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="1.3.1" />
```

Moving on...

**Turned off Ajax caching**

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
```

Not sure why I thought this would work...

**Put in a Content-Security-Policy meta tag in my index html**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://* https://* data: cdvfile://* content://* gap://ready file:;">
```

So... now I am stuck. I am testing on my new iOS 12 beta phone, but I don't think that is the problem (could be? doubt it), but my ajax calls just never happen. No errors (that I can see) or anything.

Just for thoroughness, here is my ajax call. I haven't changed this since it was working in the previous version.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: config.Path + '/account/login',
    data: { email: email, password: password }
}).done(function (data) {
    // It never gets here... ever.
});
```

Comment: Just to state a bit of the obligatory... the app works fine in my browser. It just stops working when I deploy to my real device.

Comment: Why do you think that cordova-plugin-whitelist is no longer needed? Did you tried deploy with that removed line for plugin?

Comment: I read on the Cordova whitelist page that iOS 10 didn't require it anymore, BUT I still have it in their because I know we will need it for Android at some point in the future.

Comment: make your ajax call `beforeSend: function() { alert("Ajax call");}`. Deploy your app to ios and try ajax call.. If there is alert something went wrong with URL, but we are going to find out